# What are the recommended approach for large PostgreSQL database like 30TB to 50TB?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-15

My concern is how to plan for those big databases. What needs to be considered in the case of the petabyte-scale database?

- Should I use pgpool or repmgr ?
- If I use pgpool, what will be the recommended approach to turn on failover? Since failover takes a longer time to recover in standby nodes.
- If failover is not recommended then what will be the best approach to maintain it for better performance?
- How to manage this type of large database table?

I want to know the best practices to follow for the petabyte-scale PostgreSQL database.
Looking for expert opinion.

Comment: Why should failover take longer if the database is large? Your primary concern will be backup. Other problems involve the duration of `CREATE INDEX` or autovacuum, and query performance in general.

Comment: Suppose you have 3 nodes database 
server 1 primary,  2 standby, and DB size 30TB where TPS is very high in that case failover is my concern. 
If somehow failover happens then, the new primary needs to know other standby also, but if it fails to sync with the 
standby nodes, then standby requires base backup to sync with the new primary, which is time-consuming and costly for high 
TPS and large database like 30TB to 40TB. This is my concern.

Comment: Yes you said right my concerns should be backup, creating an index, auto vacuum, and query performance but those are my second concerns. But initially, I need to follow the right architecture to build that cluster. In the PostgreSQL documentation, I found different solutions like Shared Disk Failover, File System (Block Device) Replication, WAL log shipping but which should be the right architecture for this type of large database. I need that guideline from your expertise.

Comment: Always choose a "shared nothing" architecture. There is `pg_rewind`, a kind of very fast `pg_basebackup` specifically designed for turning the old primary into a new standby after failover.